# Remove a hangfire job without instantiating a hangfire server

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I have 2 separate apps. One uses HangFire and schedules a recurring job. Another one contains tests. Tests are integrational, so they reuse actual pathways without mocking anything. Both apps have an access to the same db

As a result of running a test a recurring job appears, created by the first app, and it is desirable. However since the test is integrational - it is run on the production DB, so after the test is done I would like to remove created recurring job. And I would like to handle removing in a test.

I'd like to know if I can configure hangfire classes in the second app in a way, that would allow me to remove a recurring job, created by the first app.

If I simply configure a hangfire to use the same SQL server in the second app then a new HangFireServer will be instantiated that will start "grabbing" jobs for execution.

I can run an SQL query to remove the job, but I'd like to avoid that.

I hope I explained myself clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hangfire you can Remove/Add Job whether it is recurringjob or background job as long as you populate JobStorage first.

There probably two way to set this up.

```
JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("Your ConnectionString");;
```

or

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("Your ConnectionString");
```

Then you can now use your `RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("id")` and no need to instantiate Hangfire server. Assuming that you already have created the Hangfire Scheme before hand in other application.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you created your recurring job with an *id* you can just do RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("id"), as stated on the documentation page: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html

Comment: Yes, I know the id. What you've linked doesn't answer my question.
I don't know how to configure HangFire in a second app, so it would not do anything, but at the same time would allow me to use `RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("id")`

Comment: Do you use a database to store your jobs? Because I think you can just reference Hangfire, configure it with the correct database and  remove the job.

You could consider wrapping Hangfire in a library and use that from wherever you want to use it.

Comment: as I specified in the question - yes, I do use the db. And both apps have an access to this database. Are you saying that if I write down 
`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration     .UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString);`
and if I *won't* write 
  `app.UseHangfireServer();`
then I'll still be able to remove a Job?

Comment: Sorry for the late response - glad you figured it out :)